# WooCommerce exclude shipping classes of shipping cost calculator

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

we use the plugin from woocommerce.com for shipping costs per product (https://woocommerce.com/products/per-product-shipping/) and conditional shipping and payments (https://woocommerce.com/products/conditional-shipping-and-payments/)

But we need to exclude this products from the weight calculate for shipping costs. How can I exclude shipping classes of the shipping cost calculator (weight based)?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use this Plugin WooCommerce Weight Based Shipping[image]

Comment: Thanks Amit. But thats not the important case. We need to exclude this products from the weight calculate for shipping costs.